# Can we use TestBed for services with NativeScript?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, nativescript, karma-jasmine

I'm writing an app with NativeScript 6+ and Angular 8+.
I'm trying to write some unit tests and get them up and running.
I have read the documentation on unit testing: https://docs.nativescript.org/tooling/testing/testing
I've got some unit tests up and running with plain services.
e.g.

```
import { ItemService } from '../app/item/item.service';

describe('ItemsService Test', () => {

    let service: ItemService;

    beforeEach(() => { service = new ItemService(); });

    it('should be defined',() => {
        expect(service).toBeTruthy();
    });

    it('should have its functions defined',() => {
        expect(service.getItems).toBeTruthy();
        expect(service.getItem).toBeTruthy();
    });

});
```

I see that we can test Services with dependencies by instantiating them in the constructors and with mock services as well. 
https://angular.io/guide/testing#service-tests

Is it possible to use TestBed for our services in NativeScript? If so, can you provide an eample of how to do that?

Comment: If you continue reading the same documentation, there are examples of how you test the services with dependencies and even using TestBed. Did you try them already? If yes, please describe what issues you are facing.

Comment: @Manoj where in the documentation does it show an example with TestBed? Do you mean the Angular documentation? Can you write an answer with an example with NativeScript? Why do we need to configure the NS TestBed if we can use the Angular TestBed? Can you please go into more details?

Comment: NS hardly has few functions on top of Angular TestBed as by default TestBed is designed for Browser. I will try to run a test and update an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the services as second argument to `nsTestBedBeforeEach` then get the instance using `TestBed`

```
import { TestBed } from "@angular/core/testing";
import { nsTestBedBeforeEach } from "nativescript-angular/testing";

import { ItemService } from "../app/item/item.service";

describe("ItemsService Test", () => {
    let service: ItemService;

    beforeEach(nsTestBedBeforeEach([], [ItemService]));

    it("should use ItemService", () => {
        service = TestBed.get(ItemService);
        expect(service.getItems).toBeTruthy();
        expect(service.getItem).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var mainViewModel = require("../main-view-model"); //Require the main view model to expose the functionality inside it.

describe("Hello World Sample Test:", function() {
  it("Check counter.", function() {
    expect(mainViewModel.createViewModel().counter).toEqual(42); //Check if the counter equals 42.
  });
  it("Check message.", function () {
    expect(mainViewModel.createViewModel().message).toBe("42 taps left"); //Check if the message is "42 taps left".
  });
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I'm using Angular with NS. Do you have a solution that will work with Angular?